# The linearity conditions required by LP solver are not satisfied

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver

So for an assignment I have to find the schedule that minimizes the sum of absolute differences
between the demanded and scheduled number of workers per time interval by solving an
integer linear optimization model.

So I modeled my schedule as a set cover problem and created a row with the demanded number of workers and a row with the actual number of workers.

[image]

I take the summation of the absolute differences between the rows as object and try to minimize that.

```
=SUM(ABS(C39:Z39-C33:Z33))
```

However I get the error "**The linearity conditions required by LP solver are not satisfied**" and I don't get why since the Linearity report says ***yes*** on everything.

[image]

**X_i is the number of times a shift is chosen.*

Answer (score 0):

ABS() is not a linear function.  Who knows why excel doesn't call that out... it's internal solver does not have a great reputation.

You might try to just change your OBJ function to some penalty * uncovered jobs and see if you can get your mode up & running.  Then maybe subtract the used workers from the available, sum that up and add in a penalty for unused workers....

Answer (score 0):

As @AirSquid has already pointed out the absolute value is not a linear function. However in your context it is possible to linearize it. You can us that

minimizing `abs(sum x_i)`

is equivalent to

minimising `sum a_i`, where `a_i` are new variables with constraints `a_i>=x_i, a_i>=-x_i`.